# Can ping but can't browse ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu-16.04

I was watching something on internet and this happened.

So far, i tried

```
telnet www.google.com 80
```

and didn't get anything.

In similar question, someone said look for what is blocking your network with wireshark, but i cant download,since i cant connect.

And also
    sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling=0
this didnt work.

In dual boot also linux dist cant browse with different browser..

Comment: Just to be sure, the problem happened on two different operating systems at the same time for the same machine?

Comment: yes, i have windows 10 in another machine and internet works fine.

Comment: Have you checked to see if DNS is resolving?

Comment: in resolv.conf it was 8

Comment: it was 8.8.8.8, i erased it, to see if it works. it didnt

Comment: What happens when you try dnslookup?

Comment: what do you mean? i can dig, tho.

Comment: So from your terminal type nslookup google.com

Comment: connection timed out.

Comment: Sounds like your dns isn't resolving. I would look into that. Since you can ping, you have network connectivity, you just can't resolve names

Comment: Try putting this in resolve.conf                                                                                      nameserver 8.8.8.8                                                                                      nameserver 8.8.8.8

Comment: i thought it is sth diffucult, tho it did work, interestingly. but why did it happen in the first place while doing nothing related to it? thanks a lot btw.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain what happened. Glad we got it though. Can you +1 and mark the answer as complete?  Appreciate it!

Comment: when i have enough reputation i will +1. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this in resolve.conf nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.8.8